# I need explosives! Where can I get them?

Tags: zelda-links-awakening

I am currently working through the Angler's Tunnel, and apparently need more bombs than I currently possess. Is there a nearby place to get them? Or do I have to haul my butt all the way back to Mabe Village and pay the shopkeeper for some explosives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently [there are bombs **in** Angler's Tunnel](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/197769-the-legend-of-zelda-links-awakening-dx/49353179):

> there are bombs in Dungeon 4 [...] in the Angler's Dungeon go left in the first rm with the enemies and there are ten bombs

If you've already got them and broken all the pots and so on <s>you'll have to leave the dungeon to find more</s> (not in this case, see comments).  I don't recall anything specifically nearby but the world map isn't *too* big, so if you ignore all the distractions along the way it shouldn't take long to get to the shop :)

Comment: Ah, so there are, and because they are "flying", they refresh when you leave and re-enter the dungeon. :)

Comment: @AshleyNunn Ah, even better! I need to play that game again.